# Screen shot in android from a background app

Tags: android, android-activity

I undestood that I can't print screen another app from my app in the background due to a security reasons but there are apps that do so like apps that record the screen.
For example "DU Recorder".
So how do they are doung it in the code?

Comment: Use the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+.

Answer (score 0):

For Lollipop and above you can use the [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) API of Google to take the screenshot but you need to ask for the permission from the user.

You can find the sample screen capture code using MediaProjection [Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture)

For the devices less then Lollipop you need root permission for it.